# Defining fixed positions in the values contained in a list

Tags: grails

Good afternoon
I would like a help !!!! I have a list with the following fields:
Account, CNPj and INVOICE (value) and would you like to know how to organize this lsta again in definite positions? For example Initial position 002 and Final position 003 (contains the code of the transferor) by means of a service.

Comment: You should post a data sample, the expected result and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

use Map, for example:

```
Map fruitCounts = [
     bananas: 4,
     apples: 34,
     pears: 4
]
```

Then you access the items

```
assert fruitCounts.bananas == 4
```